# WebException: Cannot open passive data connection

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, unity-game-engine, ftpwebrequest

May be this question seems duplicate to you. But still I want exact cause of solution for my problem.

The problem is I am requesting a file from FTP with username and password. After ftp connection initialization, it throws me an exception **WebException: Cannot open passive data connection**.

But I am able to download the same file using web browser like Chrome with same username and password.

It is a Unity 3D game where user info is actually requested and some user related files will be downloaded. I am using MonoDevelop to code

The server an AWS server. Its IP address is recently changed and it was restarted. I am using the new IP and getting list of files in an XML format. I am able to parse the xml  data and be able to request the file.

Here is the code sample I am using for FTP.

```
reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri("ftp://" + serverIP + ":" + serverPort + "/" + this.receiveInfo.fileDirectory + "/" + downloadLoc));
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    Debug.Log (reqFTP.RequestUri);
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.UsePassive = true;

    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.receiveInfo.ftpUsername , this.receiveInfo.ftpPassword);
    object state = new object ();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Atleast some useful information is much appreciated as I am very new to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

The problem was with the FTP configuration. When the server was restarted the old ftp settings were imposed on the server. So it was blocking all passive ftp connections from clients. The AWS support person changed the configuration, then it started working.

After the config file was changed, the issue got solved. There is no need to change the code. The code is correct.